# Wrong Date is Display from DateComponets

Tags: swift, date, calendar, nsdatecomponents, dateformatter

```
let dateString = "2017-10-08T00:12:00.000Z"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"


let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)!



let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!, from: date)  

print("Day - \(components.day!)")
print("Month - \(components.month!)")
print("Year - \(components.year!)")

print("Hour - \(components.hour!)")
print("Min - \(components.minute!)")
print("Second - \(components.second!)")


print("Final Date - \(components.date!)")
```

By running the above code i got the output

> Day - 7
>   Month - 10
>   Year - 2017
>   Hour - 20
>   Min - 12
>   Second - 0
>   Final Date - 2017-10-08 00:12:00 +0000
>   But my Expected Date should be
>   Final Date - **2017-10-07 20:12:00 +0000**

Comment: Your date it is correct. Why do you thing the final date should be different from the original date string?

Comment: A date it is just a point in time. It has no timezone.

Comment: the components reflects the original date. You should print also the timezone component

Comment: FYI - setting the timezone on `formatter` is pointless since the date string includes its own timezone information.

Comment: @rmaddy It is pointless when converting from string to date But it is required when converting the date to string otherwise it would use the current timezone

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, but that's not being done here. But I should have been clearer that my point applies to the conversion of the String to a Date.

Comment: guys i post my solution below which working, please tell me is this right way or not.

Comment: please tell me which part is wrong in my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT SOLUTION  AS @Leo Dabus say issue with Timezone so

```
    let dateString = "2017-10-08T00:12:00.000Z"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"


    let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)!

    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!, from: date) 

   //Converting part 
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var dateComponents = components
   dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC") //Here is the logic
    let myDate = gregorian.date(from: dateComponents)!
    print(myDate)
```

Now i get the converted date as output.
**2017-10-07 20:12:00 +0000**

Comment: This is wrong You shouldn't get `2017-10-07 20:12:00 +0000` as a result

Comment: add those to your original code `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"Americas/New York")`
 `formatter.string(from: components.date!)`

Comment: why i wont the date which is in new york

Comment: check my last comment the result should be `"2017-10-07T21:12:00.000-03:00"`

Comment: `"2017-10-07T21:12:00.000-03:00"` it is the same point in time as `"2017-10-08T00:12:00.000+00:00"`

Comment: as per my requirement if i got "2017-10-08T00:12:00.000Z" from server which is utc. i need to convert it to given timezone(Newyork) so my output date should be GMT -4, which i got as a result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156410/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-leo-dabus).